# Two servers in Perforce Swarm

Tags: perforce, swarm

We have two Perforce P4D instances running. Is it possible to integrate more than one P4D into Perforce Swarm? And if yes, how? I can not find something in the documentation about it.

Comment: I think this question is for ServerFault.com.

Comment: serverfault.com has no single question about perforce swarm, so perhaps not

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Since it is about configuration of a software I have been mislead.

Answer (score 1):

No. A Swarm instance only works with one P4D. We've heard the enhancement request before though. Is there a reason you have 2 P4D servers? Just curious about your circumstances.